# How can I improve or replace my programmer art?

Tags: graphics, art

Say I'm a programmer who has done his own sprites or 3d models which would fall into programmer-ish kind of art. What steps can I take in order to improve or replace my own art?

Comment: Almost-exact duplicate: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2326/graphics-for-non-graphics-designers except Tetrad declared it to be a different question when I suggested a title change. Thus this question, I guess.

Comment: @Ricket: Yeah... that's exactly why I created this question. ;) Besides, some programmers do draw *believe it or not*. So any resource on how to get any better at it would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) If you want to improve try putting up your work on specialized sites like http://www.polycount.com/forum/

2) If you don't have time or *insert reason here* go to recruiting sites, here are a few to get you started:

http://forum.unity3d.com/viewforum.php?f=11

http://www.polycount.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?f=44

http://www.moddb.com/forum/board/recruiting-resumes

Answer (score 6):

http://opengameart.org/ its a nice resource too.

Answer (score 5):

The best way of having your programmer art replaced by real art is to carry on making a great game.

Pimp your game as often as you can - concentrate of game mechanics first - then I am sure that you'll attract some artist types - maybe even for free (join the team).

This approach is probably the only one if you're short of cash, and/or want to stay free.

Programmers art could make sure that you concentrate on the most important aspect of your game: the game itself.

There are of course places where you can grab models and art under an open license, but I would just carry on making a game if I were you.

Don't bother spending too much time trying to learn how to be an artist yourself.

That skill takes years..

Answer (score 2):

You could try making more art. The saying 'practice makes perfect' is probably applicable here.
Or, you could advertise on a site such as [Gamedev's Help Wanted Forum](http://www.gamedev.net) for an artist, saying that you've created such and such a game, with your programmer art, and looking for a improvment to the graphical quality.
The other way is to get free images, textures, and models from many sites on the internet. However, these aren't necessarily what you want. Option 2 is probably the best way, unless it's more of a learning project (not for release).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to search a skinner and/or 2D Artist who is skilled and can create that kind of art. [This](http://www.conceptart.org/forums/) is a good forum i remember, where like just skilled artists are grouped :)
You could search at Deviantart too, but there it's imo more complicated.

Or you try learning it in a professional way, but that is exhausting...

Answer (score 1):

Go to forums. Artists need you as much as you need them.

Comment: Which means he needs to convince the artists that they need what he can do.
Not an easy task. :)

Comment: I guess I have had the opposite experience.