# Is it possible to earn money with GameMaker if your game is good enough?

Tags: software-engineering, publishing, game-maker, graphics-design

I'm a graphic designer and will be graduated from school in 6 months. I would like to start developing my own game. I don't know any coding language but I'm familiar with the methods of it. When I play a game, I can understand the hole code in detail behind it theoretically.

My plan is to make a game as soon as posible and earn some cash for my coding training.. I believe I can make a simple, good looking, fun and unique game.

This may sound cheapy but I do believe in this project. So how can I earn money with it?

I have a game project written down and can create beta version of it with Game Maker in a month. But I think that wont make me earn money at all. GameMaker provides ios publishment with 199$. That I can afford but can I make money with it? Does GameMaker take percentage from your profit on ios sellings?

Can I make a beta version of this project on GameMaker and show it on Kickstarter so I can afford my future expenses like buying new laptop, attend coding classes and improve the project so people can play it on different operating systems?

Making games and earn my living with it is my dream. But turning dreams into real isn't free. If I can make roughly 45,000$ pledged for the project, in 2 years I can become self sufficient game developer and publish the game.

The project I'm talking about doesn't need physics, complex coding or anything like that. I dont think a good and addictive game have to be complicated. There are lots of financially succesfull games which are really can easy to create.

Anyway, I can design a game from scratch but can't code it entirely.. So please help me find a way for my dream. Any usefull advices will be appreciated.

**My main questions are;**

**1.** Is it possible to earn money with GameMaker if your game is good enough?

**2.** Does GameMaker take percentage from your profit on ios sellings?

**3.** Is it ok to show your game made with gamemaker on kickstarter? Or will it look like deficient?

Thanks.

Comment: Good games come from great designs ( game mechanics and accessibility ). Money comes from the publishing platform you choose to pick ( which includes the platform your games are running on). You know, where people will be buying your games. I've seen enough "shitty" looking games on kickstarter that are getting funded. And It's mind boggling people actually donate such projects ( sorry for projecting here but just look at some of those games) . Don't wanna burst your bubble. But making games is NOT a one mans job unless you have the money and time for it.

Comment: There are game editors out there that don't require programming and use a drag and drop interface. Which is great. But ultimately you might run into limitations. And scripting or programming might be a necessity even if it's about simple stuff. Having some programming knowledge is only a win-win. But you don't necessarily have to know all the ins and outs. It's going to be very time consuming if you do everything on your own. Unless you become sufficient with the tools you're working with. ( which in the end will still require energy and time)

Comment: Thank you Sidar. I know that game editors have limitations but in this project I was talking about its not important. I know its time consuming and require energy. I've made some games before in gamemaker. I agree, there are lots of "shitty" looking games on kickstarter that are getting funded with incredible prices. Which makes me wonder about if those games can funded why wont mine? I know its not a one mans job but as a digital art worker, my freelance works is not a one mans job either but that doesnt stop me. I'm not saying its the same thing but if I can, I will.

Comment: Coming from the perspective of a programmer with fairly decent art skills I can say that it is possible to do a 1 man job game. However it takes a lot of dedication and whereas I can always hire out to get additional art assets to supplement my efforts it is much harder to bring in a developer to help out after you've been working on a project for awhile. Knowing 'theoretically' the whole code behind something is a huge step away from actually implementing the solid code that a great game requires. It's always the edge cases that take most of the effort.

Comment: Uncomfortable truth:  In video games (as in much else), "good enough" doesn't imply "earns money".

Comment: Hi, Pala. I'm kinda on an alike situation, if you would like to compare notes, you can find my email on my profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider finding a programmer and work *with* him (as opposed to making him work *for* you) to make games.

Regardless of what no-coding-required-game-engine vendors want to make you believe, programming is a complex discipline, and game programming is especially difficult. People study Computer Science for decades, dedicate their entire lives to programming, yet not all get to master the hundreds of topics that are required to competently make games.

You can certainly dedicate time to "coding training", and you can probably pull out a few games by coding them, or by using those no-coding-required-game-engines, but do you really want to dedicate your time to programming and debugging your code? (remember that even if you use a graphical tool, you *will* be debugging your game)

If you do, then by all means go learn programming (I've been doing so for 19 years and there are still tons of stuff I can't do). But from what I understand, you want to design games, and make all the graphical stuff in them, so I think it you should do that, and find a good programmer, and work with him to make some awesome games.

But, by no means I'm telling you not to learn programming. Understanding the mindset of a programmer is very useful when communicating with your programmer, as well as understanding the mindset of an artist is very useful for a programmer. I'm just telling you you will be happier, and will make better games if you dedicate to do what you do best. And trust me, there's still a LOT of stuff for you to learn as a graphic designer.

There's a lot of [programmers looking for artists](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12348/how-does-a-single-programmer-make-a-game/49339#49339), and you will certainly be able to find somebody who shares your vision. If you're competent, and find a competent programmer in the same wave as you, then you're already ahead of the curve.

Now, regarding the "making money" part, I'll have to tell you it's difficult. It doesn't matter how good you think you are, your first game will suck. And the second one will suck too (just a bit less than the first one). Maybe the third one will be good enough, so some people will buy it, but maybe it will be the fourth one that will actually make you some money.

Just making a game doesn't mean it will sell. There's *way* too much to learn on how to make a good game that sells, and finding somebody to work with will get you closer to succeeding as a game creator. But if you'd rather spend your time learning programming from scratch, then go ahead.

Comment: +1 for stating the stuff that I was trying to dance around