# Good Book or Resource for 2D Game Art

Tags: 2d, graphics, art, graphics-design

I have a very clear idea for my first Game . I have immense Experience in Coding Games in LibGDX but i am very poor at game art . So far I've been hating all the characters I've drawn . Are there any good books or other resource for learning 2D Character and Game elements Art .

Thank You

Comment: Duplicate: [Learning to create better art 2d games](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16930/learning-to-create-better-art-2d-games?rq=1)

Comment: Duplicate of that, and asking for a list of resources is not a good kind of question for the site.  See the help page for more details: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask