# How to learn game graphic design for non artist?

Tags: art

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Graphics for non-Graphics Designers](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2326/graphics-for-non-graphics-designers)

I'm more into the technical aspects of a game like programming, mechanics and algorithms.

I'm no artist but I like to make games independently and I'm finding it hard to make graphics for my games. Is there anything that I could do to recuperate with this?

Comment: I'm sorry but this question has been asked several times already. Here's one: [Graphics for non-Graphics Designers](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2326/graphics-for-non-graphics-designers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it depend on what kind of graphics you are looking for. People usually go with pixelart in indie development.

If you are looking for this kind of graphics I would recommend going to deviantart.com and searching "pixelart" or "game pixelart". It will spits out countless game sprites. Download some of them and study them at 300% zoom. Some people say its good to read some books but I would say practice makes perfect. So try some of these:

- http://gas13.ru/v3/tutorials/sywtbapa_almighty_grass_tile.php
- http://garmahis.com/tutorials/pixel-art-tutorials/
- http://www.derekyu.com/?page_id=218

Pixelart is not THAT time consuming. But if you are looking for some better/complex graphics. I would say choose if you want to be a coder or a designer. Making game assets is very time consuming, and it will make your progress much slower. I would recommend hiring someone OR if you don't have enough money but you have the enthusiasm. Find somebody who shares the enthusiasm and start a small "indie studio" and cooperate.

Comment: Thank you so much dude! I guess I'll have to extend my skillset.

Answer (score 1):

The best I can say is to read some books about art, and practice using your art programs alot. Apart from that, if you aren't an artist, there isn't much you can do but hire someone else to create your graphics. :)

Here is a website dedicated to giving good tutorials about cg:

http://www.cgtutorials.com/

Answer (score 1):

Common way to 'cheat' is to use '8-bit' pixel art with with modern effects (transparency, transformations, blending) or abstract art.

For example:

- Minecraft - 3d block-based 'voxel' graphics.
- Radiant - 'pixels' that can rotate + glow effects and
  particles.
- Geodefence - simple
  shape-based art, some alpha blending, optimized particles and
  shaders.

Comment: Nice, now I see some simple art in cool games. It's what they call programmer's art eh?